# Is it possible that one column is foreign key to different table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm starting to write chat application. First i have created Database model.
But i encounter some problem.
The problem is if  sender sent  message to receiver which the receiver is offline server has to save message to send when receiver is online. But there is one problem : server has to save message type (voice,video or photo and so on).
Maybe it is not correct approach that Server save `VoiceMessageId` , `VideoMessageId` or `PhotoMessageId`. In this case this column can be `null`.

But i want to learn before create database is it possible that one column is referenced by more table.

If you have extra advice for this Database Structure write pls.
Thank you all

```
Database 
 -Users
   -Name
   -Surname
   -Age
   -JoinedAt 
   -IP
-Server
   -SenderId
   -ReceiverId
   -MessageType  (Message,VoiceMessage or VideoMessage)
   -Status (Arrived or not  -- Boolean)



 -Messages
   -SenderId   (Must Bind to UserId)
   -ReceiverId (Must Bind to UserId)
   -MessageContent (Hash)
   -SentAt

 -VoiceMessages
   -SenderId
   -ReceiverId
   -Voice (Unknown)
   -Size
   -SentAt


 -PhotoMessages
   -SenderId
   -ReceiverId
   -Photo (VARBINARY(MAX))
   -Size
   -SentAt

 -VideoMessages
   -SenderId
   -ReceiverId
   -Video (VARBINARY(MAX) or FilePath)
   -Size
   -SentAt
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a message type column, not a column with different IDs based on the type the message is.

Comment: @Larnu   I need `MessageType` Column. For instance if the message is `VideoMessage` i want to write `VideoMessageId` , else `PhotoMessageId` and so on. Is it possible to load different row Id of different Table to the `MessageType` ?

Comment: Even if it could be done,  it will lead to confusion and frustration.  I would recommend creating a separate field for each foreign key.  Each record will have one value filled in and the other two set to NULL.

Comment: If you need a message type of column, why do you "need" a separate I'd column for each type? If you need to store Duffy meta data for different message types, those should be in different tables, with a relationship to the "messages" table (with data for messages, irrespective of the type).

Comment: Consider a single Message table: MessageID (primary key), SenderUserID, ReceiverUserID, MessageSentTimestamp, StatudID, TextContent, VoiceContent, PhotoContent.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Larnu, a MessageTypeId column is the way to go.

When you look at your database design, you'll notice that all the message types have the same column with the exception of your message content. This means that you can separate the two into distinct entities/tables.

So you can create a 'generic' Message table which contains the data about who you sent it to and when, a lookup table containing the different message types (Text, Video, Image, Voice etc.) and a table containing the actual message content and then link them up like this:

```
-MessageType
    -MessageTypeId
    -Description

-MessageContent
    -MessageContentId
    -MessageTypeId (FK to MessageType table)
    -MessageContent (VARBINARY(MAX) - in this case you'll need to encode everything to varbinary, but this is something that can be handled differently)
    -Size

-Message
    -SenderId
    -ReceiverId
    -MessageContentId (FK to MessageContent table)
    -SentAt
```

Now you have a Message table that links to its MessageContents which defines the content and its size which in turn links to the MessageType telling you what type of message it is and your application code just need to convert and handle the message content appropriately.

The benefit of this design is that you can now add new content types without impacting your database schema, only application code.